# Java comment at end of brace/block

Tags: java, comments, curly-braces

Is it an accepted practice in the Java programming language to end a brace for a code block with a comment that briefly explains what code block the brace closes off? I personally would think that they are useless comments that clutter the readability of the code, but perhaps I could be wrong. For example:

```
public void myMethod(int foo) {    
    // some code
    if (foo == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMax; i++) {
            while (true) {
                // some more code
            } // end while
        } // end for
    } // end if
} // end myMethod(int)
```

Is the practice of commenting code blocks in a similar manner an accepted practice?

Comment: Wait till you have several inner blocks, seperated by 10's or even 100's of lines...then it helps.  Think about what it would look like if you had some other `if` statements within the loop...

Comment: If you have 100's of lines within a block you should probably consider  pulling a method out of there and making everything simpler.

Comment: I personally feel that its good practice to end brace blocks with suitable comments. It makes my code more understandable with least possibility of confusion about scopes.

Comment: When I do this, I increase the information slightly, for example `} // end for i` to distinguish it from a nested `} // end for j`

Comment: If your code is so confusing that it makes you feel you should re-introduce oldskool if-endif syntax, then you should make your code less confusing. :)

Comment: This is what vim's `%` is for (sort of), as well as folding (sort of).  Comments are unnecessary.

Comment: I think that Linus Torvalds said "If your code has more than three levels of indentation, then it's not a good piece of code". That said, comments at the end of code blocks may be a sign of over complexity in your code... keep it simple, it will help you (and those who read your code) have a good time

Comment: I find that putting the opening brace on a line by itself, at the same indentation as the closing brace, is the most effective way of keeping track of which braces are matched. But that is a whole separate discussion that people get really fired up about...

Comment: Sometimes code is complicated and then it can help you. But you should not add comments like this to every closing brace. Btw: your question is not only for Java. It applies to all programming languages that use braces.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is not exactly a bad practice, BUT it is a *deadly side effect* of poor Object-Oriented coding practice!

Also, this violates style guidelines and the tenets of ["self-documenting code"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting). You should never have that many brackets or a method long enough to confuse the reader about bracket placement, instead encapsulate that functionality in another method that is well documented.

Brackets imply either looping or complex if-else logic chains, good programming practice is to have a method do exactly one thing and do it well, then build your program from these smaller, atomized methods. I would read Butler Lampson's seminal piece ["Hints for Computer System Design"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/blampson/33-hints/webpage.html). It goes into some of the details on how to design good software.

So essentially, don't comment like this because:

1. It violates style guidelines
2. It shows poor Object-Oriented programming - atomize your functionality!
3. It is a deadly side effect of coding practice which goes against the underlying concepts of why Java was created - encapsulation, specifically  information hiding
4. It violates the concept of self-documenting code
5. Other programmers will make fun of you.

Answer (score 60):

My take on it is that as a rule it is NOT a good practice. As always with rules there could be exceptions but very rare.

It is not a good practice because

1. Modern editors highlight the opening bracket when you place cursor on the closing one and vice versa.
2. Most important: if there is a possibility to not see the beginning of the clause it means that the method is huge (more than half a page) which is a bad practice.
3. It adds noise to the code that will confuse readers who are used to more conventional Java coding style.
4. *Incorporating LordScree-Joachim Sauer comment*: These comments will
   be pain in the neck to maintain. So most likely it will not be maintained and the information will usually be out of sync with reality.

Comment: @LordScree: or even the corollary: "4. it will not be maintained and the information will usually be out of sync with reality"

Comment: eclipse, for example, displays block's info, if you place the mouse cursor on the closing bracket.

Answer (score 3):

I only do this when there is a place in code that has a lot of closing braces after each other. But not for every brace. Mainly I seem to use it for loops so that you can easly see what is a repeated code block.

Something that looks like this:

```
            // ...
            file.Close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then it helps to add some comments:

```
            // ...
            file.Close();
          }
        }
      }
    }//for: each file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how complicated the method or function is. Like if you have something that can be easily read and understood than there really wouldn't be a point in ending EVERY line with a comment that explains that the part has ended. That's what indentation and line breaks are for. However if you have something that is truly complex and affects a major part of your code then you should denote where that code ends and what that section does.

Answer (score 0):

If there are nested blocks of same kind, it may be confusing instead of doing good. Let's say you have 4 or 5 nested if statements(keep in mind that this only an example to demonstrate the situation, regardless of "oh you should separate those" or "make a method" suggestions) in that case you will have 4 or 5 different //end if sequenced. After a while, it makes you confuse which "end if" is for which statement, makes you spend extra effort unconsciously to see through the actual code/statements because it's not always as clean/short as your example.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, It does not help much. The code inside a loop or an if statement should not be too big.
It would have helped if there were 500 lines inside the loop.